# How can I change the highlight color of a polygon when hover on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a problem with a Leaflet map. The thing is I can successfully parse the first color and color the polygon on highlight, but when I choose another polygon, it highlights me with the same color, any ideas why? This is my code, and I attached you some screenshots with the color from database and color shown on the website. Thanks! You can test it on http://leaflet.fotoploiesti.info

```js
function culori_random() {
  var litere = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var culori = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    culori += litere[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return culori;
}

function addZona1() {
  var zona = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($zona) ?>');

  for (var i = 0; i < zona.length; i++) {

    var culoare = zona[i]['culoare'];
    console.log(culoare);
    // console.log(zona[i]['id']);
    var polygon = L.polygon(stringToGeoPoints(zona[i]['geolocatii']), {
      color: culoare
    }).addTo(groupC);
    polygon.bindPopup("<b>" + zona[i]['nume']);
    var style = {
      'default': {
        'color': culori_random()
      },
      'highlight': {
        'color': zona[i]['culoare']
      }
    };
    var highlight;

    function setHighlight(layer) {
      // Check if something's highlighted, if so unset highlight
      if (highlight) {
        unsetHighlight(highlight);
      }
      // Set highlight style on layer and store to variable
      layer.setStyle(style.highlight);
      highlight = layer;
    }

    function unsetHighlight(layer) {
      // Set default style and clear variable
      layer.setStyle(style.default);
      highlight = null;
    }
    groupC.eachLayer(function(layer) {

      // Set default style
      layer.setStyle(style.default);
      // Bind label with polygon option variable
      polygon.bindPopup("<b>" + zona[i]['nume']);
      // Mouseover handler
      layer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        // Set highlight
        setHighlight(layer);

      });

      // Mouseout handler
      layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
        // Unset highlight
        this.closePopup();
      });
      layer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        // Unset highlight
        this.openPopup();
      });
    });
  }

}
```

[image: html code]

[image: database with color field]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random color for each polygon,right now you are generating only one random color:

```
groupC.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  var culoare = culori_random();
  // Set default style
  layer.setStyle({
    'color': culoare
  });

  // Bind label with polygon option variable
  polygon.bindPopup("<b>" + zona[i]['nume']);
  // Mouseover handler
  layer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    // Set highlight
    setHighlight(layer);
    console.log(layer)
  });

  // Mouseout handler
  layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    // Unset highlight
    this.closePopup();
  });
  layer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    // Unset highlight
    this.openPopup();
  });
});
```

demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/30GJmkxC4A0CGHbY74l4?p=preview

to preserve the color after hover you need a array to save the random generated colors

Comment: sorry typo, you need the element that you hover over, i think `$('.leaflet-interactive');` is

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work, it says that setstyle it's not defined

Comment: i don't see any function body with that name

Comment: ,,layer.setStyle is not a function", ,,this.closePopup is not a function" are the errors

Comment: Then I should remove the sethighlight and unsethighlight functions

Comment: Well, we're on a good way. It colored the polygon on the right color, but not on hover, it colored by default with this color